# Construct a multiplication table for $\mathbb{Z}_2[i]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Construct a multiplication table for $$\mathbb{Z}_2[i]=\{a+bi|a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_2\}$$.

I have figured this table out for the most part. I know that each side has $0,1,i,1+i$, but $(1+i)(i)=i-1$, and what would that become in $\mathbb{Z}_2[i]$? I have the same question for $(1+i)(1+i)$, I don't know how to reduce these in terms of the mod.

Comment: Note that, in $\mathbb Z_2[i]$, $\;i-1=i+1$, and $(1+i)^2=1^2+i^2=0$ or $(1+i)^2=2i=0$

Comment: How do you define $\mathrm i$ in an extension of $\mathbb Z_2$? Still as a root of $X^2+1$? because then $\mathrm i=1$, since $X^2+1=X^2+1^2=(X+1)^2=(X-1)^2$, so $1$ is the only root.

Comment: @Vercassivelanouos I would rather think to use the quotient ring $\Bbb Z_2[I]/(I^2+1)$ with $i=I+(I^2+1)$. So you get two solutions to the equation $x^2=1$. It's not a field extension, as you get zero divisors, but it is a well-defined ring with four elements.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, I completely agree with your solution, but how did you know what the result was in the mod? I'm not sure how to mod complex expressions

Comment: Simply "mod" the coefficients $a$ and $b$ when you have $a+bi$; note that $2=0$ and $-1=1$ in $\mathbb Z_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others also mentioned , we can generate the field ${Z_2[x]}$ with irreducible polynomial ${x^2+x+1}$ ,and the elements are ${\{0,1,x,x+1\}}$  , here ${x^2=x+1}$,and  ${-1=1}$ , ${0=(1+i)^2 = i+i}$

- Here ${(x+1)^{-1}=x}$, cayley table may looks like..[image]

Comment: Why are you confusing $x^2+1$ ($i$) and $x^2+x+1$ ($\zeta_3$) ? (with $i$ I mean $\Bbb{Z}_2[i]$ is not a field, it is the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^2+1)$)

Comment: yes, I know, but wouldn't be easier for him to construct table.

Comment: @SSA But that's not the same ring at all. You can't just change which ideal you divide by. We are spcifically _not_ using an irreducible polynomial, so we don't get a field.